# Explicit on first generic but infer the second in TS?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to be explicit on the first generic, but implicit (infer) the 2nd one?

for example a pick function:

```
function pick<T extends { [K: string]: any }, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: U): T[U] {
    return obj[key];
}

interface Obj {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

const obj = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
};

// works, available keys are inferred
pick(obj, 'bar');

// error: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
// Is there a way I can tell to TS to infer the 2nd generic instead of expecting it explicitly?
pick<Obj>(obj, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const pick = <T extends { [K: string]: any }>(obj: T) => <U extends keyof T>(key: U): T[U] => {
    return obj[key];
}

interface Obj {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

const obj = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
};

// works, available keys are inferred
pick(obj)(bar)

// error: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
// Is there a way I can tell to TS to infer the 2nd generic instead of expecting it explicitly?
pick<Obj>(obj)('foo');
```

You can by currying the function; Let me know if this helps

Comment: Yeah, that the one I went with. Unfortunately as I read there isn't a proper solution for partial inference so far :/. Thanks for your answer!